# Setting the max width of columns in proportion in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Is it possible to set the maxwidth of columns in proportion to the width of another column?

Basically i have a grid with 2 columns. First columns control can increase or decrease in size at run time (so i have set the columns width to auto), which makes the grid to keep growing and second column goes out of screen. Is there any way that i can set the max width of first column to a proportion to the width of second column?

Or is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: why dont you just set the MinWidth for your second column?

Comment: @nit Thanks for reply. I tried doing that but still the first column keeps on increasing and eventually starts going out of screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the width of your second column to a constant value and the width of your first column to *. That would give the first column the remainder of the page width.

If both need to be linked in percentage, like 60% to 40%, then you could set the first column width to 6* and the second column width to 4*.

-Note- This only works with a grid as container where you define columndefinitions...

Comment: Might be i did not explain clearly. In my case Column1 and column2's width gets increased/decreased at runtime. so there is no point in assigning them a fixed/proportional widths as you have suggested.

Comment: So there's no relationship whatever as in width between the two or a constant in the two? In that case I can only imagine two possibilities:

- Setting the parent container to a width. It might resize the summed size of both columns to that width. Not sure however how this handles the resize event..
- Or that you should create an event which handles re-sizing the columns. You could then check the screen width, apply the new width to the column that is resized and apply the remaining width to the other column...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it through the LayoutUpdated event of the grid.  You would have to check the sizes of the columns and set properties accordingly.  I have never tried this, but I don't know of any other way to do it.

Greg